# I don't understand why I can't delete Outlook messages with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to slap together a system using Outlook rules and VBA to copy the body of an email message into a plaintext file for further processing, then delete the message from Outlook.

I can't use Outlook rules to delete the message, because I can't control the order in which Outlook executes the actions in the rule. If I could do "Run a script, and then delete" as an action, it would be good enough as-is. However, Outlook will only allow me to delete the message first, and THEN run the script, which is useless to me.

I obviously don't know VBA from a hole in the ground, but from what I've been able to glean from googling, I've got the following VBA which does what I need EXCEPT I can't figure out how to delete the email.

Code so far:

```
Public Sub SaveBody3(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As NameSpace
    Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim i As Integer  
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    i = 1

    For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
        If InStr(olMail.Subject, "my_very_specific_subject_line") Then
            Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("\\path\to\textfile\filename_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhnnss") & ".txt", ForWriting, True)
            ts.Write (olMail.Body)
            ts.Close
            olMail.Delete 'Shouldn't this delete??
            Set ts = Nothing
            Set fso = Nothing
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next olMail

    Set Fldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I will ask you what I ask everyone who has a similar question: why bother trying to delete? Just archive or auto-archive your Inbox at appropriate intervals and that should clean up the old items.  That said, I would expect the `.Delete` method should delete the msg (and it does when I test a simple case). Do you get an error or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs perfectly on my computer.  Check your trash bin.  If you're evaluating the email being deleted based on an a search of all mail with a certain subject line, you won't notice the email being deleted, because it is simply moved to your trash bin (but still exists).  Empty your trash bin, run your code and then see if anything shows up in the trash folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes For Each does not work as expected. Skipping items as the index changes.

The reccommendaton is to delete backwards.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343(v=office.15).aspx
"The Delete method deletes a single item in a collection. To delete all items in the Items collection of a folder, you must delete each item starting with the last item in the folder."

If **nothing** works in the current loop try this.

```
Dim j As Long

For j = Fldr.Items.count To 1 Step -1

    If TypeOf Fldr.Items(j) Is mailitem Then

        Set olMail = Fldr.Items(j)

        If InStr(olMail.subject, "my_very_specific_subject_line") Then
            Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("\\path\to\textfile\filename_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhnnss") & ".txt", ForWriting, True)
            ts.Write (olMail.body)
            ts.Close
            olMail.Delete
            Set ts = Nothing
            Set fso = Nothing
            i = i + 1
        End If

        Set olMail = Nothing

    End If

Next j
```